# Catching if a web text field is tapped on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, uitextfield

In my iOS app I have a `UIWebView` which works fine. What I am unable to get is which function is invoked when user taps on a text field in a displayed webpage. To make my problem clearer:

If I display google in the `UIWebView` and then tap on the search bar, `UIWebView` automatically pops up the keyboard. I want to know how does `UIWebView` detects the search bar being tapped. What function is invoked on this tap?

I am sure it is not

```
webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

Method, for it is not navigating to any new page.

Comment: I dont think there is any way to detect the touch on a search field only, an option is `touchesbegan` but this will be for complete view. Why dont you try posting keyboard notifications? Try `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`, `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`